# Is this graphic card compatible with my motherboard in terms of PCIe?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, compatibility, hardware-rec, pci-express

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PCIe Generation 3.0 graphic board running on old mainboard Generation 2.0 or earlier?](https://superuser.com/questions/461896/pcie-generation-3-0-graphic-board-running-on-old-mainboard-generation-2-0-or-ear)

today sadly my good old graphic card died :(.

I'm now in the need of a new one, but since a lot time passed I'm unsure if my motherboard is still compatible with a newer graphic card.

My motherboard is a "gigabyte ga-ma790x-ud4".

(further information on the motherboard should and can be found here: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3002#sp)

I would like to buy an "ati radeon hd 7870" by ASUS, they call it "HD7870-DC2TG-2GD5-V2"

(further information about the graphic card here: http://www.asus.com/Graphics_Cards/AMD_Series/HD7870DC2TG2GD5V2/#overview)

I know that I have pci-express slots on my motherboard, but I'm afraid there might be issues with the different possible existing PCIe-Standards (PCIe 1.0 / 2.0 / 3.0 ). But I'm no expert in this area.

Can someone help me out by clearly telling me if this graphic card will work with my motherboard ?

Thanks a lot for every thought you're sharing with me.

Comment: Yes, it almost certainly will. I don't even think your PCI 2.0 16x slot would be bottlenecked by most graphics cards.

Comment: so my motherboard supports PCIe 2.0? Thanks for your comment

Comment: It says so in the link you provided: *The PCIEX16_1 and PCIEX8_1 slots support ATI CrossFireX™ technology and conform to PCI Express 2.0 standard.*

Comment: Ah nice. I mostly paid attention to the specification-section and there it isn't clearly stated. Thanks

Comment: It's actually in the **Specification** tab, under **Expansion Slots**. For some bizarre reason, they hid it between the second and third list item.